# Why compiler don't provide default operator= for template class?

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

My code,

```
template<typename T>
class NamedObject{
public:

    NamedObject(std::string& name, const T& value):nameValue(name), objectValue(value)
    {

    }

private:
    std::string& nameValue;
    const T objectValue;
};

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    NamedObject<int> obj1(std::string("Obj1"),3);
    NamedObject<int> obj2(std::string("Obj2"),3);

    obj2 = obj1; //this line gives error


    return 0;
}
```

I am getting error,

> Error 1   error C2582: 'operator =' function is unavailable in
>   'NamedObject'  c:\users\pkothari\documents\visual studio
>   2008\projects\stackoflw\stackoflw\stackoflw.cpp   39

I have not provide any operator =, shouldn't compiler provide default one?

@Edit for shown as duplicate: I agree with const, reference can refer to member of another object.

Comment: You wrote a non-defaulted constructor, so no compiler provided `operator=` is generated

Comment: @PasserBy, That's not true. Constructor has nothing to do with `operator=`

Comment: @Ajay Oh, oops, that's a hole in my memory fixed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Template has nothing to do with it. Your class has a `const` data member, and has a reference to `string`. You'd need to remove `const` attribute has well as reference specifier from the `string` data member. I would suggest you to implement the class without using templates.

Comment: I know it has nothing to do with Template. I tried removing const as well. But reference can refer to member of another object, right?

Comment: Reference is not pointer. An int* can point to something else later, but an int& cannot reference to something else later.